# Set a fixed message to all users without starting the bot

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

I have implemented a Telegram bot in botframework. My question is how can I set a fixed message to all users without starting the bot (as you know each bot in Telegram is started by clicking on a start button)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, you cannot initiate any message to the user without starting the bot. However, the question has an answer outside the botframework. You can set a fixed message (like greeting message) to all users using `/setdescription` command in `@BotFather`. You can see the result in the following image:

[image]